Converting GFA to rGFA
I used nf-core/pangenome which created a GFA file. We found panGraphViewer in order to visualize nf-core/pangenome GFA file. However panGraphViewer requires a rGFA. However, it supposed to be able to convert GFA to rGFA but in my case it failed to do it.
I looked into gfatools but did not understand how to use it.
